# Create log error and php warning in root file

Tags: php, warnings, error-logging

I created an `smtp` coding to send bulk emails and it was not a problem on the first day but at next day it slowed down or the emails were not sent and a log error appeared in my root file. error log:

`PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/vodrllia/federalus-fedus3.xyz/email.php on line 19`

where line 19 is

```
$rt = $rt+1;
```

and this lines up and down

```
$tts = 720;
while(true){
    if($tts>=720){
        $tts = 0;
        $rt = file_get_contents("runtime.txt");
        $rt = $rt+1;
        unlink("runtime.txt");
        $runtime = fopen("runtime.txt","w+");
        fwrite($runtime, $rt);
        fclose($runtime);
```

please help me to fix this error

Comment: What's the contents of the file runtime.txt?

Comment: Error is on line number 19, right? And you mentioned code from line number 257 in the question.

Comment: unlink can act weird if you create the file again just after deleting it, try removing that line it and just updating the value in the file. also could do `file_put_contents("runtime.txt", (int) file_get_contents("runtime.txt") + 1)`

Comment: the contents of runtime.txt is only the number of emails sent indicates that it sends 10 emails in each series.

Comment: Dear Lawrence Cherone, I did all the said items and the error was resolved, but my emails are not sent automatically.